# When I press F3 something covers the coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

Whenever I press <kbd>F3</kbd> I see a long line of words that are covering the coordinates. I've tried changing it but nothing will work.

Comment: That looks like it's your graphics card name covering the coordinates. I don't actually know if there's a way to fix this

Answer (score 12):

You have a few options...

1 - Resize your Minecraft window. If you make it wider the text should align better:

[image]
[image]

2 - Get a resource pack with a decent font (something narrow or smaller). With the text being smaller it should no longer overlap that far.

3 - Not really an option, but if you run Minecraft on a graphics card with less text in its name it would resolve your issue as well.

Comment: @AlecMurr also, going off the resource pack point, there is a setting in the language settings called something like "force unicode" which condenses all of the letters by consequence.

Comment: Using a different driver or a mod that lets you customize the F3 menu would be far simpler

Answer (score 10):

Reduce GUI Scale or Increase resolution. Your screen space is too small for all of this info to fit.

Comment: Changing the resolution alone doesn't necessarily work, because the GUI (and text) would scale up as well. It is important to change the window width to make use of the widescreen effects. Changing the GUI scale is an option.

Comment: change window width = change window resolution. You are saying the same thing. With a few different tries at a few different resolutions, he will find a setting that allows him to get good performance and good readability for the debug output

Comment: I'm talking about changing the width and height together (to keep the same aspect ratio). That way the GUI just scales up.

Comment: @dly Only if it's set to auto.

Comment: @dly brother, in most cases the resolution changes but the aspect ratio remains the same. Most modern games (or Windows OS if you will) have adaptive settings for screen resolution, such as to not bring up options that are outside of the spectrum of the monitor and those which are not equal to the monitor's native aspect ratio.

For example, you plug in a 4:3 monitor you gonna have different resolution options compared to a 16:9 or if you have ultra wide 21:9 that's a third list of options.

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov when using window mode you won't be restricted to your screen's aspect ratio. Just pull a corner or side of the game frame to whatever size you want. That's what I was referring to and that's also what my screenshots show.

Comment: Agreed, he can do that in window mode. If that is what you were referring to it is also an option

Comment: I wonder how this duplicate of my answer was able to get 10 upvotes, while I got 3.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to dly's solutions you can also set your GUI scale (in video settings) smaller, then the font in <kbd>F3</kbd> is also smaller. But all other UI elements (like inventories or chat) will be smaller, too.

Answer (score 0):

Go into settings → video settings → gui scale and change it to 3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/315655)